# Symbolic link got deleted after reboot in mac

Tags: macos, mac, symbolic-link

Normally when i add symbolink link using ln -s , it will stay after restart/logout.

But if i make symlink to /Volumes/ for example :

sudo ln -s /Users/Desktop/temp /Volumes

The link will be gone after restarting. Why ? and how to make it permanent ?

Comment: Can you see the symlink after creating it?

Comment: @JasonK. yes, i've been working on it but after every restart it's gone. Only happen when i do symlink to /Volumes/ , it won't happen when symlink to anywhere inside my home folder.

Comment: Several entries in the root directory of a Mac are virtual, system-managed interfaces which get repopulated at reboot.